# fill SVG path with pattern without stretching

Tags: html, css, image, svg, background-image

I'm trying to use edit this [example](https://tympanus.net/Development/ShapeOverlays/index2.html) and fill the wave with a pattern

```
<svg id="shape-overlays" class="shape-overlays" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>
                    <pattern id="img4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="180" height="180">
                        <image xlink:href="./pattern/menu-3.png" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="180" />
                    </pattern>
                </defs>


                <path class="shape-overlays__path"></path>
                <path class="shape-overlays__path"></path>
                <path class="shape-overlays__path"></path>
                <path class="shape-overlays__path"></path>
            </svg>
```

CSS

```
.shape-overlays__path:nth-of-type(4) {
 fill: url(#img4);
 stroke: red;
 stroke-width: 1;
}
```

the SVG path is filled with pattern image but isn't repeated and is also stretched

I would like to have it repeated as a pattern, if is not possible I would like to use a big image as cover but keeping proportion

Comment: please provide a working test case in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve the issue I changed **preserveAspectRatio** to "xMidYMid slice" instead of "none"

```
<svg id="shape-overlays" class="shape-overlays" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" >
```